# Compare two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, compare

I need to compare two arrays. If I test if Object1==Object2 I am testing if the objects point to the same address in memory. I actually want to compare them based on their properties values. Let me show  you what I mean.

I have a class in javascript:

```
function MyClass(var1,var2,var3)
{
   this.var1 = var1;
   this.var2 = var2;
   this.var3 = var3;
}
```

Now I will be able to create a new object of that class as:

```
var myNewObject = new MyClass(1,"hello",3);
```

and I will be able to access the properties of that object as:

```
myNewObject.var2 = "New value";
```

I have two arrays:

```
 var array1 = new Array();
 var array2 = new Array();
```

both arrays are populated with MyClass objects. In other words if array1 has 3 elements I know that they will be of type MyClass meaning I could do something like:  `array1[2].var1 = foo`

**I will like to compare array1 with array2 based on the values of their properties **

for example if

```
   array1 = [ [1,"hello",4] , [0,"foo",5] ]; 

   array2 = [ [0,"foo",5555] [1111,"hello",4]];

   note: // [1,"hello",4] means a MyClass object with var1=1, var2="hello", var3 = 4
```

I will like to have a method that will tell me the changes. In this example var1 changed to 1111 and var3 changed from 5 to 5555.

I will probably be able to do it if I spend a lot of ours doing it. I am not to good at algorithms and maybe there is a simple way of doing it.

---

### edit

I will like to know the changes that I will have to make to array1 in order to make it equal to array2.

Comment: are we guaranteed that array1 and array2 contain the same number of objects? And do we need to compare all items in array1 to all items in array2 or just array1[i] to array2[i]?

Comment: no the arrays may contain different number of objects. I want to know what will you have to do to array1 in order to make it equal to array2 doing the fewest number of operations not taking into account comparisons. so maybe you will have to add I item to the array to make it equal. or maybe remove an item. Changing one item's property to match the array vs droping the item and creating a new one will be considered doing a bigger operation. Hope I explain my self clearly. If not please ask whatever I am not explaining correctly. Thanks for the help

Comment: And remember that most importantly I want to store maybe in an array or string the things that I have to do to array1 in order to make it equal to array2. making them equal I will just copy the array. I am interested in seeing the changes needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Making it equal" sounds like `array1 = array2.slice(0)`, but that seems not to be what you want. So try the following:

```
for (var i=0, l=Math.max(array1.length, array2.length); i<l; i++) {
    if (! array1[i]) {
        alert("You need to make a copy of "+array2[i]);
        continue;
    }
    if (! array2[i]) {
        alert("You need to delete "+array1[i]);
        continue;
    }
    for (var j in array2[i]) {
        if (array2.hasOwnProperty(i)) // needed only when MyClass has a prototype with enumerable properties
            if (array1[i][j] !== array2[i][j])
                alert("You need to change "+j+" of "+array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just added a bracket for this nice piece of code to stand. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Using literal notation instead of pesudo code:

```
> array1 = [ {var1:1, var2:"hello", var3:4},
>            {var1:0, var2:"foo", var3:5}
> ];
> array2 = [ {var1:0, var2:"foo", var3:5555},
>            {var1:1111, var2:"hello", var3:4}
> ]; 
>
> I will like to have a method that will tell me the changes. In
> this example var1 changed to 1111 and var3 changed from 5 to 5555.
```

How do you know to compare the first member of the first array with the second member in the second array? Similarly for array1[1] vs array2[0]?

The objects do not seem to have unique identifiers or a particular order in their container arrays, so how do you know which ones to compare to determine differences or changes required?

Comment: I know that the arrays will contain a MyClass objects so I know what are the things I need to compare. I also know that I just have to make modifications to array1. And you are right there is not a primary key for comparison. I will like to make as few changes as possible in order to make array1 equal to array2